# Votes don't count after reputation rise

Tags: support, reputation, voting

I just went above 15 reputation and went to see the upvotes I gave on a couple of topics, and none of them were there, although the message popup says that my votes are remembered and will show up when my reputation rises above 15.
So I gave the upvotes again and now they work as expected. 
So either it is a bug, or the message should be changed so the voting is forbidden.